# IAP purchase error after updating to Android API 29

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an application where there are some items which can be purchased (IAP). After updating the application to target API 29, these IAP fail with the following error:

`Service connection is disconnected.`

I have double checked that this problem didn't occur when the application targeted API 28.

Looking for any suggestions on how to solve this issue.